# Alternative 3G Modem to replace Vodafone Mobile Connect Lite?

Tags: 3g

I'm based in the UK and have a Vodafone K3520-Z 3G Modem which by default comes with Vodafone Mobile Connect Lite to manage connecting to their 3G network.

The software's awful and I'm fairly sure it's responsible for some blue screens I've been having.

Does anyone know of any alternatives to replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - and I have also seen it responsible for blue screens, You can install the standalone driver for the modem, then simply use it as any other modem e.g. create a new connection, choose it as the device and ring a number - I forget the number off by heart, but if you look in the connect software (If you don't mind launching it once more) it should be there.

Also, you can try [updating the firmware](http://help.vodafone.co.uk/system/selfservice.controller?CMD=BROWSE_TOPIC&PARTITION_ID=1&CONFIGURATION=1058&SIDE_LINK_TOPIC_ID=30218&TOPIC_ID=30218&TOPIC_TYPE=0&STARTING_ID=0&TOPIC_NAME=Vodafone%20Data%20Devices&PARENT_TOPIC_ID=-1&PARENT_TOPIC_TYPE=0&SOURCE_FORM=BROWSE_TOPIC) in the device - it is still bad, but works a bit better. (If you can't find it on the FAQ part, try [the forum](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/index.php?act=idx) - it is where I got an update from.

Comment: That's fantastic - never even thought about that.

I couldn't find then number in the software, but after a bit of Googling around the required details are:
Number: *99***1#
Username: web
Password: web